# replacing values with .loc

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I am trying to loop through a DF column and get just the URL key from a column of strings.  I have printed every stage of this loop and it works correctly.  However when printing the DF after the loop I only see the column I create with the correct values and the loop has now replaced other values in those rows a NaN.  what am i doing wrong here?
#clean playlists link for just key and create new column 'key'

```
for i, value in enumerate(tats['Playlist Link'].values):
    splitstring = str(value).split('/')
    value = splitstring[len(splitstring)-1]
    if "?" in value:
        value = value[0:value.index('?')]
    else:
        value = value
    tats.loc[i, 'key'] = value
```

Comment: you may want to fix the indentation after the for loop

Comment: please elaborate for a noob like myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for i, value in zip(tats.index, tats['Playlist Link'].values):
    ...
```

Comment: i like your style, friend.  works like a charm

Comment: Welcome my bro.